# nvim errors on ubuntu wsl

Tags: lua, neovim, packer

I'm trying to use nvim on Ubuntu WSL.
I installed it with AppImage because with `apt` it seems to be quite old version.

```
curl -LO https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/latest/download/nvim.appimage
chmod u+x nvim.appimage
./nvim.appimage
```

Then I'm trying to install packer etc to customize it following this blogpost: [Turning Neovim into a Full-Fledged Code Editor with Lua](https://mattermost.com/blog/turning-neovim-into-a-full-fledged-code-editor-with-lua/)

Every time I open nvim  `./nvim.appimage` I get this:

```
Error detected while processing /home/rr/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /home/rr/.config/nvim/lua/vars.lua:4: attempt to index local 'g' (a function value)
stack traceback:
        /home/rr/.config/nvim/lua/vars.lua:4: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /home/rr/.config/nvim/init.lua:10: in main chunk
Error detected while processing /tmp/.mount_nvim.aiftKrm/usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: .../.mount_nvim.aiftKrm/usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:1: attempt to index field 'g' (a function value)
stack traceback:
        .../.mount_nvim.aiftKrm/usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:1: in main chunk
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: .../.mount_nvim.aiftKrm/usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:1: attempt to index field 'g' (a function value)
stack traceback:
        .../.mount_nvim.aiftKrm/usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:1: in main chunk
Error detected while processing /tmp/.mount_nvim.aiftKrm/usr/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim:
line   42:
E121: Undefined variable: s:did_ft
Error detected while processing /tmp/.mount_nvim.aiftKrm/usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/man.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: ...mount_nvim.aiftKrm/usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/man.lua:1: attempt to index field 'g' (a function value)
stack traceback:
        ...mount_nvim.aiftKrm/usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/man.lua:1: in main chunk
Error detected while processing BufReadPost Autocommands for "*":
Error executing lua callback: ...m.aiftKrm/usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/editorconfig.lua:6: attempt to index field 'g' (a function value)
stack traceback:
        ...m.aiftKrm/usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/editorconfig.lua:6: in function <...m.aiftKrm/usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/editorconfig.lua:4>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

My current set up is:

```
.config/nvim/
├── init.lua
├── lua
│   ├── keys.lua
│   ├── opts.lua
│   ├── plug.lua
│   └── vars.lua
└── site
    └── pack
        └── packer
```

> init.lua

```
cat .config/nvim/init.lua
--[[ init.lua ]]

-- LEADER
-- These keybindings need to be defined before the first
-- is called; otherwise, it will default to "\"
vim.g.mapleader = ","
vim.g.localleader = "\\"

-- IMPORTS
require("vars")      -- Variables
require('opts')      -- Options
require('keys')      -- Keymaps
require('plug')      -- Plugins
```

> plug.lua

```
cat .config/nvim/lua/plug.lua
-- [[ plug.lua ]]

return require("packer").startup(function(use)
    use "wbthomason/packer.nvim"
    use "nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua"
end
)
```

> vars.lua

```
 cat .config/nvim/lua/vars.lua
--[[ vars.lua ]]
vim.g = vim.api.nvim_set_var
local g = vim.g
g.t_co = 256
g.background = "dark"

-- Update the packpath
local packer_path = vim.fn.stdpath("config") .. "/site"
vim.o.packpath = vim.o.packpath .. "," .. packer_path
```

I am new in using vim/nvim and lua, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things I want to point out.

- Don't use appimage of neovim because sometimes it does not work very well the plugin managers and also with some plugins, instead build it from source.
- For building from source and modern configuration of neovim `(with lazy.nvim, lsp, linting)` you can checkout my [github repo](https://github.com/sadikeey/nvim) for that.
- Third thing is that you don't have to set variables like this instead

```lua
-- Don't do like this(it's a mess).
vim.g = vim.api.nvim_set_var
local g = vim.g
g.t_co = 256
g.background = "dark"
-- You can easily set variables using nvim api like this
vim.opt.background = "dark"
```

- Let me know if you encounter any issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in the end I deleted nvim and vim and reinstalled nvim from source.
I would like to why you think it is a mess to add these `local g` variables. Many guides use them.
It helps to type less.

Comment: No no I was not talking about setting a variable `local g = `, I was talking about using `vim.g` instead of `vim.opt`.